# Взятие параметра id из GET запроса

Tags: java, get, rest

Есть GET `http://localhost:8088/property/123`

или

Есть GET `http://localhost:8088/gaz-mas/1722`

REST `@GetMapping("/property/{id}")`

Сделал фильтр который должен проверить в БД есть ли такой `id`, прежде чем пропустить дальше.

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "SecurityRestFilter", urlPatterns = "/property")
public class SecurityRestFilter implements Filter {

@Autowired
PropertyService propertyService;

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityRestFilter.class);

public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    Long id = (Long) servletRequest.getAttribute("id");
    String login = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin();
    
    if (!propertyService.getPropertyByIdAndPersonalAccount(id, login)) {
        response.sendRedirect("/pageNotFound404");
    }
    chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    log.debug("Init SecurityRestFilter");
}
```

}

Проблема заключается в том, что не получается взять этот `id` из реста
(`property?id=123` - такой вариант знаю, но я не могу изменить передачу `id` в ресте)

знаю что можно еще задать типа в input `id = "id"`, а в фильтре `request.getAttribute("id")`  но тоже менять формы и добавлять айдишники не желательно

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно получить `id`?

Comment: Почему не получается? Приведите полный код своего метода контроллера, в котором вы пытаетесь получить этот параметр

Comment: @iksuy добавил код

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае id - это PathVariable. Вместо

```
Long id = (Long) servletRequest.getAttribute("id");
```

попробуйте сделать так:

```
Map pathVariables = (Map) servletRequest.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
Long id = Long.parseLong(pathVariables.get("id"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Long id = (Long) servletRequest.getAttribute("id");
```

замените на

```
Long id = Long.parseLong(servletRequest.getParameter("id"));
```

Comment: Long id = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(servletRequest.getAttribute("id"))); - согласен, но проблему не решает))

Comment: @GoodWin 1) юзай getParameter, как у меня. 2) String.valueOf не нужен, т.к getParameter возвращает строку

Answer (score 0):

Переменные пути доступны в контроллере, выполняющемся с помощью сервлета `dispatcher`, но не доступны в фильтре. Поэтому вам надо парсить URL самостоятельно, чтобы извлечь оттуда требуемый параметр. Есть много способов это сделать, например с помощью регулярных выражений.

```
String path = servletRequest.getRequestPath();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/property/(\\\d)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
matcher.find();        
String id = matcher.group(1);
```